# check if input ends with specific character

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have this basic input field:

```
<input type="text" name="one" />
```

How can I make sure user ends the input value with a specific character, for example comma (,) before running server-side code?

Example:

> "hello world" (invalid)
>
> "hello world," (valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use HTML5 pattern validation? It's very easy and no Javascript to maintain.

**Demo Snippet:**

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="one" pattern=".*,$" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
var str = 'hello world,'
if (str.includes(',',-1)) alert ('valid')
```

Note that includes is an es6 feature and will only work in modern browsers, see the link I posted above for further information and a polyfill.

Comment: You should also note that this an ES6 feature, and that he should be doing such validation on the server-side, which questions if the code will even be javascript. If it is nodeJS, then it should be `.contains`, otherwise something in PHP, etc...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using HTML5's input `pattern` attribute, which validates input with a regular expression.  The form will not be allowed to submit in modern [browsers that support this attribute](http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern) - but you should always validate user input server-side as well.

```css
input:valid {
  background: lime;
}

input:invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="(.+?),$">
```

The CSS used in this example is purely to display when the input is valid (green).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="one" onkeypress="validateForm()">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["one"].value;
    if(x.charAt(x.length-1) == ','){
    console.log("true");
    }else{
   console.log("false");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There javascript function endsWith which check is string ends with certain character

```
 var chr  = "Hello world,";
    if(chr.endsWith(",") {

    }else{

    }
```

as kenny said it wont worked on IE..MDN has provided protoype function for this function

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      } 
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic method is similar to Marcin C's:

```
function endsWith(str, end) {
    var $len = str.length,
    $endlen = end.length;
    if (substr($len - $endlen, $endlen) === end) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an ID, in order to easily extract the value:

```
var textInputValue = document.getElementById("myIdHere").value;
```

Then use regex to see if it matches your pattern:

```
if( textInputValue.match(/,$/) ){
     alert("the input is valid!");
} else {
     alert("sorry, invalid input"); 
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybsuyx6e/

Answer (score -1):

```
/,$/.test("hello world,") // true
```

Comment: Why would you use a regex? Why?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz it's short, flexible and doesn't break old browsers. Why not?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz why wouldn't you use a regex?

Comment: @KennyFellows Regex's are meant to find occurrences. In this case scenario, the OP knows exactly what he is looking for and where it should appear. A comma at the end of string. A simple `String.prototype.charAt(String.prototype.length-1)===44` should do the trick, and it is more efficient because it doesn't go through the searching algorithm associated with a regex.